# Use match contains with conditional logic

Tags: karate

I need to assign a variable to "Yes" if the array contains a specific value, and it not, assign it to "No". Example:

```
* def value = "222"
* def array = ["111", "222", "333", "444"]
```

I am looking to do something like that.

```
* def var = (array contains value) ? "Yes" : "No"
```

Thanks